# `formControlName` - Validation not truthifying the `disabled` sate of the submit button

Tags: angular, angular5

In my form `Validation` my `formControlName` not works as per expected. there is a `fileupload` field in my form. once the file updated i am expected to `enable` my `submit` button. But this is not happening.

here is my component code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-doc-upload',
  templateUrl: './doc-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./doc-upload.component.css']
})
export class DocUploadComponent implements OnInit {

    uploadForm:FormGroup;
    fileUpload : File = null;
    uploadedFileName:string = "Select File...";

    constructor(private formbuilder:FormBuilder) {

        this.uploadForm = formbuilder.group({
            fileUpload : ["", [Validators.required]] //added fro enable
        })
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    handleFileInput(files:FileList){

        this.fileUpload = files.item(0);
        this.uploadedFileName = this.fileUpload.name; //works fine
    }

}
```

my html file:

```
<h5>Document Upload</h5>
<form [formGroup]="uploadForm" >


<div class="form-group">
<label for="title" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Document</label>
<div class="cols-sm-10">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile" 
    (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" aria-describedby="fileHelp" formControlName="fileUpload">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">
        {{uploadedFileName}}
    </label>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <input type="submit" [disabled]="!uploadForm.valid" value="Generate States" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can bind an input of file type to a reactive form. I tell you that after some quick tests.

My way of doing it is to handle the file separately. Since you alredy do, you can simply review the disabled condition of your button :

```
<input type="submit" [disabled]="fileUpload" value="Generate States" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">
```

Comment: In case if I have more than one form fields what will happen? if this is the way then why should I use the form control?

Comment: You put 2 conditions on your button : `fileUpload || form.invalid`. You don't have to use the formControl, I don't know who told you that but you really don't need to.

Comment: Read the documentation about forms. That's what I did, and right after finishing it, I have been able to provide my help to people like you or to make complete forms. If I were you, I would focus on reactive forms.

Comment: But this is what I practiced : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formvalidation?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Then practice more, on cases likes that ! Personally I discovered that on a personal project where I wanted to upload pictures. The form was useless, so I tried a form control. Seeing this was also useless, I used a view child reference and the change event like you did, and adapted my conditions in my html. You will never have an all-purpose solution, so you need to use what you know and what you discover along your developments.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @trichetriche has said, it **does not appear the Angular team has any intention to add support for `<input type="file" ...>` with regards to reactive forms** as you can see from this [Angular GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3466) that has been closed regarding the matter.

That being said there are alternatives, personally I've used the following simple approach to validate my file uploads:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-form',
  template: `
  <form (onsubmit)="submitFile()">
    <input type="file" (change)="onFileUpload($event)">
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!fileUpload">Submit</button>
  </form>
  `
})
export class DynamicFormComponent {
  public fileUpload: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  public onFileUpload(event) {
    //Do any file validation if needed
    this.fileUpload = true;
  }

  public submitFile() {}
}
```